# Jsoup url, get url by link name

Tags: java, url, jsoup

I wanna get url by the link name.

```
<a href="download.asp?softid=1&amp;downid=2&id=65367" target="_blank">download</a>

<a href="www.baidu.com" target="_blank">ad</a>
```

so what i want is the first url as the link name is download.

My question is how to get url by link name.

I know a complete solution is to get all elements and use if(a.text().contains(download) ). But I guess there is a simple way.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well, the best way would be to get all the < a>s, which contain hrefs, and get the hrefs attributes. Just like this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("whatever url").get();

Elements a = doc.select("a[href]");

String href;

for (Element elem : a) {
    href = a.attr("href");
}
```

Now.. Which hrefs you wanna get is enterely up to you. But I think you'd have to use the

```
.contains(""); 
.endsWith(""); 
.startsWith("");
```

Oh, and maybe you could try using the getters from the doc variable.

.getElementsByAttributeValue("a[href]", "download");

Answer (score 2):

Use a pseudo-selector. For example,

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements a = doc.select("a[href]:contains(download)");
```

Depending on what exactly you are trying to accomplish, you might want to use containsOwn to avoid searching within child elements, or use matches/matchesOwn if you want to use a regex to get elements that contain ONLY the text "download". That regex would be

```
^download$
```

See the [Selector documentation](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html).

Comment: Thanks,I tried a[href]:contains(download) before, at last i found it's the encoding problem.Thanks.

Comment: doc.select("a[href]:contains(download)") this does NOT work